# do I / should I test omniahuth-facebook

Tags: rspec, omniauth

I'm implementing this for the first time and am curious whether I should test this? It looks like a pain to test. Any simple resources appreciated or thoughts. I am obviously testing our post callback authentication in remainder of specs.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to test with rspec+capybara integration specs. You could check my sample rails application https://github.com/lucassus/locomotive it has specs for testing login via facebook, see: https://github.com/lucassus/locomotive/blob/master/spec/features/user_facebook_sign_up_spec.rb

Generally you could very easily mock omniahuth-facebook with the following code snippet:

```
feature 'Sign up via Facebook' do

  background do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Sign in'

    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
      provider: 'facebook',
      uid: '123545',
      credentials: {
        token: 'facebook token'
      }
    }
  end

  # ..do test here
end
```

Comment: so what would the test be? checking the that uid is '12345'? I'd like to test user creation after OmniAuth is mocked but just really not sure who to do it.